# Jenkins: remove old builds automatically

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

Is there any plugin or script to remove old build data from Jenkins? There are docker images associated with the builds, so they are taking lots of space. I don't want to keep the build data for more than 30 days.

Seen this plugin : [Jenkins: remove old builds](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Discard+Old+Build+plugin)
But it seems buggy and many people faced problems with it

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest sticking with the plugin as you already figured out. 
It works well for me to get rid of old builds and associated artifacts (archive step).

Have a look at the various parameters you can set with it-
https://jenkinsci.github.io/job-dsl-plugin/#path/pipelineJob-logRotator

In your case - setting "daysToKeep" to 30 should do

Be aware It will not remove the docker images; for that, you need to implement separate strategy; say 'docker system prune" or "docker image prune"

check this -
https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/image_prune/

Comment: We've been using the dicard builds plugin since 2013 to manage our instance with over 4000 jobs, some running many times/hr and others 1-2x/yr. No issues. Not using docker.images.

Answer (score 0):

I have used several of the of Groovy Jenkins scriptlets described here: https://github.com/jenkinsci/jenkins-scripts/tree/master/scriptler

Search for 'bulk' and you'll find several flavors. My favorite is https://github.com/jenkinsci/jenkins-scripts/blob/master/scriptler/bulkDeleteBuilds.groovy which allows you to delete job builds in a specified range.

You can run scriptlets automatically as part of a build, or for more control manually from the Scriptlet console or even from a chron Jenkins job.